# Number of tries until Failure with n different independent Bernoulli experiment

Tags: probability, distributions, geometric-distribution

I have 3(n) coffee machines in an office. I have a historical log of these machines, and I know in the last ten days(t) how many times they failed to make a coffee.

For example:

- machine 1: 10 failures in 100 tries
- machine 2: 20 failures in 1000 tries
- machine 3: 50 failure in 300 tries

I know that I can use the Expected Value of the Geometric distribution for a machine to calculate the mean number of tries before the first failure.

**Question:**
How many times does one person need to use coffee machines in this office until he gets the first failure?

How can we formulate this problem?

Comment: If I get it correctly, it depends on the probability that person chooses which machine to use. Does this person always use the same machine? Does each machine have a probability of 1/3 to be chosen?

Comment: After reading the answer of @Tim, I think his approach is the most straightforward approach with considering people uniformly choose the machines. 

I think it is possible to take the number of tries each machine had into account and calculate the possibility of using that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed in the comment by @periwinkle, the result depends also on the probability of the machine by a user. I would assume that the machines are chosen uniformly at random, but any other probability distribution can be used instead. Recall the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

$$
P(A) = \sum_i P(B_i \cap A)
$$

The probability of a failure of $i$-th machine depends on the probability of picking this machine $\pi_i$ and the probability of failure $p_i$. The events are independent, so jointly the probability is $\pi_i p_i$, and the overall probability of failure is

$$
p = \sum_i \pi_i p_i
$$

That's the probability we would plug-in into the [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) to calculate the expected number of runs till failure $1/p$.

Let's verify this using simulation

```r
pi <- c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)
p <- c(10/100, 20/1000, 50/300)

sim <- function(n) {
    for (i in 1:n) {
        # pick machine
        k <- sample.int(3, size=1, prob=pi)
        # simulate failure or no failure with probability p[k]
        if (runif(1) < p[k]) {
            return(i)
        }
    }
    warning("no success")
}
```

That gives us the following result that confirms the analytical solution:

```r
> set.seed(42)
> summary(replicate(50000, sim(1000)))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.00    7.00   10.44   14.00  116.0
> 1/sum(pi * p)
[1] 10.46512
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to take the number of tries each machine had into account and calculate the possibility of using that machine, instead of assuming that the machines are chosen uniformly at random?

Comment: @DSaad not sure what you mean by "number of tries" but if machines are choosen not uniformly at random but users prefer to use some machines more than others, then you change the $\pi_i$ probabilities to something else. On another hand, if you want to assume that the events are not independent (e.g. if user used the machine he is more likely to use it again) this would get *much* more complicated and more details would be needed to answer it.

Comment: I meant by "number of tries" that, for example, the chance of machine 1 being used is  100 / (100 + 1000 + 300).

Comment: @DSaad so just change $\pi_i$ to any values such that $\sum_i \pi_i = 1$.